# Golang Gorm error migrating struct

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a small mistake in my small application and I really do not see where it can come from. So I have 4 structs, one of the 4 struct has several one-to-one relationships.

I connect to my database and use automigrate to migrate my 4 structs and create the necessary tables.
The problem is at this point, it does not create anything in the database and in the terminal I have this message:
(Error 1060: Name of the 'id' field already in use)

My code 
**main.go**

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
_ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)

var db *gorm.DB
var err error

const (
mysupersecretpassword = "cr9ih_pvr9f9kc75n#bz&y%(@+^&1_#hr0^)-$kv%n3dh84$^w"
)

func main() {

db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "root:root@/test?charset=utf8&parseTime=True")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer db.Close()
db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Ads{}, &Type{}, &Category{}, &Location{})

}
```

**models.go**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Email    string `json:"email" form:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password" form:"password"`
    active   bool   `json:"active" gorm:"default:0"`
    level    bool   `json:"level" gorm:"default:0"`
}

type Type struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name" form:"name"`
}

type Category struct {
    gorm.Model
    CatID uint   `json:"category-parent" form:"category-parent" gorm:"default:0"`
    Name  string `json:"name" form:"name"`
}

type Location struct {
    gorm.Model
    Location string `json:"location" form:"location"`
}

type Ads struct {
    gorm.Model
    User     User     `json:"user"`
    Type     Type     `json:"type" form:"type"`
    Category Category `json:"category" form:"category"`
    Title    string   `json:"title" form:"title"`
    Content  string   `json:"content" form:"content"`
    Location Location `json:"location" form:"location"`
}
```

Waiting for an answer that could put me on the right path :)

Answer (score 1):

> AutoMigrate will ONLY create tables, missing columns and missing indexes, and WON'T change existing column's type or delete unused columns to protect your data.

I would guess that one of your tables already exists, and the `id` column in that table is a different type than what `gorm.Model` wants to create.  I would figure out which table it is by doing:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Ads{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Type{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Category{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Location{})
```

and seeing where it fails.  Then, I would backup that table (just in case), and then either just drop the table completely, or rename the id column to `tmp_id`, see if automigrate fixes it, and if so, drop the `tmp_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I've found Gorm will not log proper error or any error if it has permission issues on the user.  For example the table existed when logged in as root, but the user I was logging in as didn't see it at all, Gorm just ran through Migration without creating the table or altering it (even though it was different schema) just didn't report any permission issue at all.